# Simple Data access / download ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, database, devexpress

I am a winforms programmer and need to setup a data access website for our sql server database. The database contains weather data (wind, temperature, etc..). I would like users to be able to select a start and stop date and the to download the dataset. I know this should be simple to build, but I would like some advise on what is the best technique.

Do I need entity framework? We have a license for Developer Express ASP.NET. Any ideas to use, since I am totally confused about all the options available and I haven't build any ASP.NET website in a long time.....

Thanks,

Erik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a first pass/prototype, I'd suggest you use ADO.Net and see how it runs with your datasets. Then, once things are clearer I'd maybe look into an ORM. Based on the use case you mention ORM *might* be overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Yes with license for Developer Express ASP.NET. you can use Entity Framework

If you want work with ORM technology. mapping relational object; yuo have wizard who facilitate your cretaion of database and mapping

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx

You can also use just ADO.Net with adapter of datas, stored procedure, dataset datatables,  etc....